# How do I temporarily remove proxy settings?

Tags: bash, proxy

I set my proxy settings using the following command

```
export http_proxy=http://proxyusername:proxypassword@proxyaddress:proxyport
```

When I do

```
echo $http_proxy
```

I get

```
http://cavs@students:cavsuon@proxy.uonbi.ac.ke:80
```

However when I do

```
unset $http_proxy
```

I get an error

```
-bash: unset: `http://cavs@students:cavsuon@proxy.uonbi.ac.ke:80': not a valid identifier
```

So I did

```
$http_proxy = ""
```

which also gives me the following error

```
-bash: http://cavs@students:cavsuon@proxy.uonbi.ac.ke:80: No such file or directory
```

How do I completely remove this proxy setting?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! @chris: If Jobin's answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The correct way to use `unset` is without the `$`, so you can do the following:

```
unset http_proxy
```

to unset your proxy settings or you can even use the following:

```
http_proxy=""
```

Note that there is no space in before and after the `=`.